# Simple XML serializing non mandatory fields

Tags: java, android, xml

When I try parse a java object to xml. My xml doesn't look fine and it doesn't have close tags , I have a value which is a not required and I am seeing the value.

This is my class :

```
@Root(name="root")
public class Example {

    @Element(name="message" , required = false)
    private String text;

    @Attribute(name="id", required = true)
    private int index;

    @Attribute( required = false)
    private int index2;


    public String getMessage() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
 }
```

And when I did this :

```
      Serializer serializer = new Persister();
      Example example1 = new Example();

      example1.setIndex(111111);
      String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "yourFolder";
        File folder = new File(path);
        File file1 = new File(folder, "qqq.xml");

      try {
        serializer.write(example1, file1);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My output XML looks like this :

```
<root index2="0" id="1
```

**Why I have a index2="0" ? and don't have id="1"  ?**

Comment: Is the `<root index2="0" id="1` whole content of the xml file?

Comment: @aborocz when I change a primityve type to object it works fine :)

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka try using String for both id's